# Merge array in rest api in response

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working with rest api in PHP and I'm getting an array output result. But I want to get data nested within `cat_id`. This is my actual output result below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16
            [user_id] => 1
            [cat_id] => 11
            [image] => abc.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16
            [user_id] => 2
            [cat_id] => 11
            [image] => xyz.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16
            [user_id] => 2
            [cat_id] => 12
            [image] => cde.jpg
        )
```

I want to show the output result via `cat_id` like the following array

```
[0] => Array
(

    [cat_id] => 11
        {
            [image] => abc.jpg
            [user_id] => 1

            [image] => xyz.jpg
            [user_id] => 2

        }
    [cat_id] => 12
        {
            [image] => cde.jpg
            [user_id] => 2
        }   
)
```

Here is my code in controller

```
$users['rec'] = $this->Model_users->get_categories();
$responseJSON = array("Status" => true,"Message" => "Records","Result" => $users['rec']);
header("content-type:application/json");
$response = json_encode($responseJSON);
echo $response;
```

Here is my model

```
$this->load->database();
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('mytable');
$query = $this->db->get();
if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 ){
    $rows = $query->result_array();
    return $rows;   
}else{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: what should you try for that?

Comment: @BhargavChudasama : i am confused for solve this

Comment: your array isn't in even proper format.

Comment: @dexter : understand, but i hope you understand my problem, how can i resolve this ?

Comment: please provide the sensible format about what you expect as a output.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
$cats = array();

foreach ($rows as $value) {
    $cats[$value["cat_id"]][] = $value;
}
```

Now `$cats` should be the way you want it.